# How can I view/inspect my Mac’s Parameter RAM (NVRAM)?

Tags: mac, applications, software-recommendation, nvram

Inspired by [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/47193/26522) I started looking for apps that allow to read the data saved in my Mac’s Parameter RAM. Aside from a [very antique](http://www.tucows.com/preview/207381/PRAM-Inspector) (pre OS X) application for Classic, I could not find any. Is there any way to access the info stored in the PRAM on current Macs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To clarify, for PowerPC based Macs, this memory was called PRAM, but for Intel based Macs, [the proper name is NVRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379).

To show the contents of the NVRAM or even manipulate them, you can use the `nvram` shell commando in Terminal. For info on usage, execute `man nvram`.

If you just want to display the entire contents of the NVRAM, you can execute it with th `-p` parameter:

`nvram -p`

Comment: Very helpful comment, thank you. Do you think it’s a good idea to reflect your correction in the question title as well? If so, please be my guest.

Comment: @myhd, I'm not sure, I'll leave that up to you. There are no wrong questions though :)

Comment: `nvram` is also the name of the facility on PPC OS X as well.

Comment: Thanks! Now I found out why a totally wiped Mac still had a locale other then English in the install routine. NVRAM contains a variable with the key `prev-lang:kbd` and the value  `LL:NN`, where LL is the language code and NN a numerical keyboard layout id. Was `de:92` in my case.