# How can I find Bluetooth MAC addresses of previously connected BT devices?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Does anyone know a way or an application that shows the MAC address of previously-stored Bluetooth devices? What I’m trying to find is a MAC address of an item saved via Bluetooth on an iPhone that I can’t sync as the item is missing. I’ve found some applications on Android that show the MAC address for previously-stored Bluetooth devices but none on Apple. All I can find is Bluetooth scanners which won’t work for what I want to do.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47193/where-does-os-x-remember-previously-connected-bluetooth-devices?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this. However, you can make an backup to your computer, and open it in a backup viewer. The steps may vary depending on what program you use to open the backup, but for iMazing:

1. Open File System
2. Open System Shared Containers
3. Navigate to `SysSharedContainerDomain-systemgroup.com.apple.bluetooth/Library/Database`
4. That folder should contain two SQLite databses (`com.apple.MobileBluetooth.ledevices.paired.db` and `com.apple.MobileBluetooth.ledevices.other.db`)

Export the two files, and from there you can try to find the device's address using a database browser.

Good luck!